# How to share an fstab'd external HDD between users "www-data" and "pi"?

Tags: linux, permissions, raspbian, fstab, external-hdd

I've been working through these [two](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-owncloud/) [tutorials](https://www.resilio.com/blog/how-i-created-my-own-personal-cloud-using-bittorrent-sync-owncloud-and-raspberry-pi), in the hopes of setting up a Raspberry Pi to run Owncloud and Resilio Sync in tandem. First, I installed Owncloud and gave it access to a mounted external HDD as recommended in the guide, and it works, but trying to "merge" privileges for the external HDD so that both it and Sync have read/write access to the directory has proven frustrating (i.e. it doesn't work on Sync's end).

Sync is owned by the "pi" user. Owncloud is owned by the "www-data" user. I tried chown-ing Sync to run as "www-data" but that had no positive effect. Here's my current fstab entry:

```
UUID=[UUID HERE] /mnt/ownclouddrive auto nofail,uid=33,gid=33,umask=0027,dmask=0027,noatime 0 0
```

Also, it appears I need to fstab the drive in order for Owncloud to work.

What am I overlooking? I'm a novice to Linux, so any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It's weird that the guide you linked to only has instructions for using an NTFS formatted external drive.  It would be better to use a drive formatted with a Linux native filesystem, such as ext4 or xfs (both of which have case-insensitivity options that might be useful if storing files for MS Windows clients), that automatically supports Linux user and group ownership and permissions.  It would also be faster because ext4/xfs/etc would be running in kernel space, while ntfs-3g runs in user space as a FUSE module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `fstab` to `...gid=www-data,umask=0007,dmask=0007...` to allow group access to the drive. Read `man umask`.

Then, add user `pi` to the `www-data` group: `sudo adduser pi www-data`. Read `man adduser`.

Logout and login - groups are set up at login time.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you waltinator.

Comment: @qlabsmusic Please click the checkmark to "accept" my answer, if it solved your problem, and might help others.